# Undefined property: Cake\ORM\Query::$texto

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

DocumentosController:

```
public function documento($idDocumento) {
   $documentos = TableRegistry::get('Documentos');
   $documento = $documentos
                  ->find()
                  ->select('id', 'titulo', 'texto')
                  ->where(['id' => $idDocumento]);
  }
```

documento.ctp:

```
<div>
  <?= $documento->texto; ?>
</div>
```

> Error: Notice (8): Undefined property: Cake\ORM\Query::$texto
>   [APP/Template/Documentos/documento.ctp, line 3]

$id if it has value, if it returns a number, but the query does not work because I tried to add `->first()`, but it returns:

> Internal Server Error [500].

Comment: If you are retrieving just a single record, you may be better off doing it with `->get($idDocumento)` instead of `->find()->where(['id' => $idDocumento])`.

Comment: Thank you! It has worked

Answer (score 1):

you have to use set() method, the main way to send data from your controller to your view.
Once you’ve used set(), the variable can be accessed in your view:

```
public function documento($idDocumento) {
   $documentos = TableRegistry::get('Documentos');
   $documento = $documentos
              ->find('all')
              ->select('id', 'titulo', 'texto')
              ->where(['id' => $idDocumento]);
   $this->set('documento ', $documento );
}
```

for reference https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#setting-view-variables

you can also use get(),

```
$documento = $documentos->get($idDocumento);
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass an instance of the \Cake\ORM\Query to the view. You must execute the query by calling first() or all() or execute() to get a result.

Comment: first() or all() or execute() Any of the three gives error: Internal Server Error [500].

Comment: Update your question to show the code where you've tried this?